# Deploying Nextjs application to Vercel failed

Tags: javascript, next.js, deployment, vercel

I want to deploy my app to Vercel, but getting this error at build
It working fine locally. Can you tell me how to fix it?

Github code: https://github.com/Dzenoo/Project-Management-Tool

```
Running "npm run build"
> project-management-tool@0.1.0 build
> next build
- warn You have enabled experimental feature (serverComponentsExternalPackages) in next.config.js.
- warn Experimental features are not covered by semver, and may cause unexpected or broken application behavior. Use at your own risk.
Attention: Next.js now collects completely anonymous telemetry regarding usage.
This information is used to shape Next.js' roadmap and prioritize features.
You can learn more, including how to opt-out if you'd not like to participate in this anonymous program, by visiting the following URL:
https://nextjs.org/telemetry
- info Creating an optimized production build...
<w> [webpack.cache.PackFileCacheStrategy] Skipped not serializable cache item 'Compilation/modules|javascript/auto|/vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/build/webpack/loaders/next-flight-css-loader.js!/vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/build/webpack/loaders/css-loader/src/index.js??ruleSet[1].rules[4].oneOf[7].use[1]!/vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/build/webpack/loaders/postcss-loader/src/index.js??ruleSet[1].rules[4].oneOf[7].use[2]!/vercel/path0/styles/projects/projects.module.css|sc_client': No serializer registered for Warning
<w> while serializing webpack/lib/cache/PackFileCacheStrategy.PackContentItems -> webpack/lib/NormalModule -> Array { 1 items } -> webpack/lib/ModuleWarning -> Warning
Failed to compile.
./app/(auth)/login/page.jsx
Module not found: Can't resolve '@/components/auth/LoginForm'
https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/module-not-found
./app/(auth)/signup/page.jsx
Module not found: Can't resolve '@/components/auth/SignupForm'
https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/module-not-found
> Build failed because of webpack errors
Error: Command "npm run build" exited with 1
BUILD_UTILS_SPAWN_1: Command "npm run build" exited with 1
```

Comment: The paths to the failing imports are not using the right casing. They should be `@/components/Auth/LoginForm` and `@/components/Auth/SignupForm`, as the `Auth` folder is capitalised.